# How to properly write a wrapper for a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

> Now that most your navigation is in place, you should make it so that
>   the different pets are shown in the `PetList`. To do this, modify the
>   `/` route in the `App` component so that instead of specifying a
>   `component` property, you specify a
>   [**`render`**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)
>   property. This property be assigned a callback function that takes in
>   a set of props, and returns a `<PetList>` element with those props *as
>   well as* the original **`pet`** prop.
>
> *Tip:* Try declaring this function as a local variable inside of the `App`'s `render()` function, and then passing that function value as a
>   prop. This can help with readability.
>
> Once this works, you should be able to see the list of pet cards when
>   you visit the `/` route.

This is the main problem, of which I have solved how to route without the wrapper. The problem is once I try write this into a local variable I get lost. A few questions I had include:

- Where do I place this local variable? It is placed before the return statement in the render function correct?
- The link above shows how to do this, however; I do not know how to apply this to the situation
- I don't really understand `...` and `...rest` what is the purpose of `...` alone as well as with `...rest`?

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid py-4">
        <div className="container">
          <h1><Link to='/'>Adopt a Pet</Link></h1>
        </div>
      </header>

      <main className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-3">
            <AboutNav />
          </div>
          <div className="col-9">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' render={() => 
                <PetList pets={this.state.pets} />
              } />
              <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutPage} />
              <Route exact path='/resources' component={ResourcesPage} />
              <Redirect to='/' />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer className="container">
        <small>Images from <a href="http://www.seattlehumane.org/adoption/dogs">Seattle Humane Society</a></small>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do I place this local variable? It is placed before the return statement in the render function correct?

Yes. You have this:

```
render() {
  return (
    // ...
    <Route exact path='/' render={() => 
      <PetList pets={this.state.pets} />
    } />
    // ...
  );
}
```

The text is telling you to do something like this:

```
render() {
  const renderPetList = () => <PetList pets={this.state.pets} />;

  return (
    // ...
    <Route exact path='/' render={renderPetList} />
    // ...
  );
}
```

> I don't really understand `...` and `...rest` what is the purpose of `...` alone as well as with `...rest`?

I can't tell what this is in reference to, but I'm guessing you've seen it in the context of object destructuring.

This is a contrived example, but 
Suppose you wanted to create a wrapper for `<button>` that takes a bunch of props that you'll pass straight to the `<button>` and one that you won't (let's say "`mySize`"), because you want to do something else with it first. You could do it this way:

```
const MyButton = ({ mySize, childen, disabled, tabIndex, onClick, children }) => {
  const className = mySize === 'big' ? 'big-button' : 'normal-button';

  return (
    <button className={className} disabled={disabled} tabIndex={tabIndex} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

That's really verbose, though. Instead of repeating the names of all of the props we want to pass to `<button>`, we can use `...` (the "spread operator") to pick out certain props to put in variables to do with as we will while the *rest* (ergo `...rest`, although you can call it whatever you want) go in an object, making it much more concise:

```
const MyButton = ({ mySize, ...restProps }) => {
  const className = mySize === 'big' ? 'big-button' : 'normal-button';

  return (
    <button className={className} {...restProps}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```